# CMD - Batch con FTP - Error subiendo excels (.xlsx)

Tags: excel, cmd, batch, ftp

El .bat sube el archivo pero parece que lo corrompe, me marca que se sube correctamente y compruebo en el FTP y en efecto veo que se ha subido pero al abrirlo (descargándolo al pc o abriéndolo con una librería php) dice que no se puede leer. ¿Qué pasará?

*Si lo subo a través de filezilla manualmente no hay problema, pero claro, quiero poder subirlo a través de mi bat.

```
        @echo off
        echo user adminz> ftpcmd.dat
        echo passxxxx>> ftpcmd.dat
        echo cd "/public_html/">> ftpcmd.dat
        echo put "C:\Users\doc.xlsx">> ftpcmd.dat
        echo quit>> ftpcmd.dat
        ftp -n -s:ftpcmd.dat ftp.web---.net
        del ftpcmd.dat

        timeout /t 10
```

Comment: Has configurado el modo de transferencia a `binary`?

Comment: no, ¿como lo puedo hacer compañero?

Comment: Antes de la transferencia simplemente llamas al comando de ftp: `binary` sino el modo normal sería `ascii`.

Comment: Gracias crack, solucionado.